# Subsets and Elements of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-software

I have a question I have been trying to answer which is:
Let $A = \{x ∈ \mathbb N | x^2 < 37\}$ and $B = \{3k+1 | k ∈ \{1,2,3,4\}\}$ be sets. List out the elements of A and the elements of B and List all the subsets of B.

My answer for the subsets of $B =$ {∅}, {{1}}, {{2}}, {{3}}, {{4}}, {{1,2,3,4}}, {{1,2,3}}, {{1,3,4}}, {{1,2,4}}, {{1,2}}, {{1,3}}, {{1,4}}, {{2,3,4}}, {{2,3}}, {{2,4}}, {{3,4}}.
My answer for the elements of $A = 1,2,3,4,5,6$
My answer for the elements of $B = 1,2,3,4$

Is this correct or am I getting something wrong? I feel uncertain about my answer.

Comment: The comment about negative numbers and $A$ is moot, since $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Minor remark: depending on your definition of $\mathbb{N}$, $0$ may also be an element of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The elements you have listed for set $A$ are correct. The elements in set $B$ are incorrect. For the elements in B, you are looking for numbers in the form $3k+1$, where $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, not the values of $k$ itself (ie $3(1) + 1 = 4$, $3(2) + 1 = 6$, etc.)

The way you're finding subsets looks fine to me!

Comment: Oh, so would this be correct:                                                                                       Since k ∈ {1,2,3,4} it means 3k+1 can be: 3 * 1 + 1 =  4  OR
          3 * 2 + 1 = 7  OR
          3 * 3 + 1 = 10  OR
          3 * 4 + 1 = 13
Therefore the elements of B = 4, 7, 10, 14

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by this?

Comment: Your first comment is correct. I had read it wrong...